# Assign filename to pdf from cell value

Tags: excel, pdf-generation, vba

I have a macro that saves the excel file into a PDF one:

```
   Sub PDF()
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:="C:\Report.pdf", _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End Sub
```

How do I assign the pdf name to a value in a specific cell in excel? And how I do specify the save directory as the same where the excel file is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify your code like below, your `ActiveSheet` will get exported as a `.PDF` to the same folder as the `ActiveWorkbook`, and with the name defined in cell `A1` of the `ActiveSheet`.

```
Sub PDF()
    Dim SaveAsStr As String

    SaveAsStr = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=SaveAsStr & ".pdf", _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

Note that you may want to refine this code a little since this will return an error if you run it in a workbook that is not yet saved (i.e. there is no valid path to save the PDF at) or if the cell with the cell with the filename is empty.