# how to get the file name to = range("b3") & now()

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-pdf

So in this string of code it does everything i need it to except naming correctly. It will pop open a box that asks me where to save but not an option for a name furthermore, i would like it to save as..

```
range("b3") & format(now(), ddmmyy)
```

how can i get that to fit into this and have it formatted correctly?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range

Set xSht = ActiveSheet
Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
   xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
Else
   MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf 
& "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination 
Folder"
   Exit Sub
End If
xFolder = xFolder + "\" + xSht.Name + ".pdf"

'Check if file already exist
If Len(Dir(xFolder)) > 0 Then
    xYesorNo = MsgBox(xFolder & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do 
you want to overwrite it?", _
                      vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
    On Error Resume Next
    If xYesorNo = vbYes Then
        Kill xFolder
    Else
        MsgBox "if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", 
vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make sure the file is 
not open or write protected." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", 
vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"
        Exit Sub
   End If
End If

Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
    'Save as PDF file
    xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xFolder, 
Quality:=xlQualityStandard

'Create Outlook email
Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
With xEmailObj
    .Display
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = xSht.Name + ".pdf"
    .Attachments.Add xFolder
    If DisplayEmail = False Then
        '.Send
    End If
End With
Else
  MsgBox "The active worksheet cannot be blank"
  Exit Sub
End If

Unload Me
CLOSE1.Show

End Sub
```

I'm just not sure how to have it set the way i need it to be set. Like i said everything else works, i just need it to save as my range and date.

Comment: Your problem is your line `xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xFolder`, the Filename is activating the `FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)`, you need to create a variable, e.g. "SaveFileName" and replace `xfolder` in the `Filename`.  View [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098120/assign-filename-to-pdf-from-cell-value), it should help you. You can also do a Google search for "excel vba use cell value as filename in exportasfixedformat" it will bring up a number of links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without explanation I'm not sure how all that code is relative but assuming cell `B3` contains text only, your example is close -- but is missing quotes.

It should be:

```
Range("B3") & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy")
```

Comment: I'm trying to get that set as the file name in that long string. To where when I kick off the sub that is the save as name, then it converts to pdf and lastly kicks off the mail to function.